# How Can I solve this node-sass problem on terminal mac ? I cannot also run this package

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, terminal, node-sass

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQCnO.jpg)

I do not know why this problem occurs. I can also run my node-sass package on visual studio code.

I did rebuild nodes-sass but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

npm --depth 9999 update
npm rebuild node-sass

what npm --depth 9999 update is doing?

"If no package name is specified, all packages in the specified location (global or local) will be updated. As of npm@2.6.1, the npm update will only inspect top-level packages. Prior versions of npm would also recursively inspect all dependencies. To get the old behavior, use npm --depth 9999 update ."

Comment: Thanks. I did whatever you said but still is not working !

Comment: the same issue?

Comment: Do you have this issue from the beginning or after updating vs code?

Comment: yes. I deleted vscode and installed it again. still the same

Answer (score 0):

node-sass won't support Node 15 till there is a 5.0 release made